# Tkinter lags when using iconphoto method

Tags: python, tkinter

When launching this app, the window lags by opening a short window then the full size window. Here is a GIF:
[image]

I've narrowed down the cause to have to do with the iconphoto() method. When I comment it out, there is no lag:[image]

What I've tried:

- Threading
- self.after(50, self.master.iconphoto(False, photo))

Is there any way this can be fixed?

Here is the script for class App():

```
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        # threading.Thread(target=self.launch5).start()
        self.master.title('Screenshot')
        photo = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(THIS_DIR, 'Screenshot.png'))
        self.master.iconphoto(False, photo)
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.pack(expand=YES)
        self.pack_propagate(False)
        f = Frame(self, bg=self['bg'])
        self.color_frame = Frame(f, width=scaled(50), height=scaled(50), bg='#777777')
        self.label = Label(f, text='Off', font=('Times', '16', 'bold'), bg=self['bg'])
        self.color_frame.pack(side=LEFT, padx=scaled(20))
        self.label.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=scaled(20))
        f.pack(expand=YES)

        self.on_off = False
        self.bring = False
        self.color_win = False
        self.win = None
        self.start = (0, 0)

        threading.Thread(target=self.launch4).start()

    def launch(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.screen_ocr).start()

    def launch2(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.get_hex).start()

    def launch3(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.bring_back).start()

    def launch4(self):
        keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+~', self.launch)
        keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+q', self.launch2)
        keyboard.add_hotkey('alt+w', self.launch3)

    def launch5(self):
        self.master.title('Screenshot')
        # photo = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(THIS_DIR, 'Screenshot.png'))
        # self.master.iconphoto(False, photo)
        self.master.resizable(False, False)

    def screen_ocr(self):
        flags, cursor, (x, y) = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()
        if not self.on_off:
            self.start = (x, y)
            self.on_off = True
            self.color_frame.configure(bg='#5D1725')
            self.label.configure(text='On')
            self.master.iconify()

        else:
            try:
                pdf = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(self.start[0], self.start[1], x, y)), extension='pdf')
                with open(os.path.join(THIS_DIR, 'Scratch.pdf'), 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(pdf)
                self.on_off = False
                self.label.configure(text='Off')
                self.color_frame.configure(bg='#777777')

                os.startfile(os.path.join(THIS_DIR, 'Scratch.pdf'))
            except SystemError:
                self.on_off = False
                self.label.configure(text='Off')
                self.color_frame.configure(bg='#777777')
                messagebox.showerror(title='Screenshot Error', message='Screenshots must start from the top left and end with the bottom right.')

            except pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError:
                self.on_off = False
                self.label.configure(text='Off')
                self.color_frame.configure(bg='#777777')
                messagebox.showerror(title='Tesseract Error', message='Tesseract OCR not found. Make sure that the PATH environment variable contains the path to the Tesseract OCR folder.')

    def bring_back(self):
        if not self.bring:
            self.master.iconify()
            self.bring = True
        else:
            self.master.deiconify()
            self.bring = False

    def get_hex(self):
        if not self.color_win:
            self.win = ColorWindow(master=self.master, bg='white')
            self.win.get_color()
            self.clipboard_clear()
            self.clipboard_append(self.win.hex)
            self.update()
            self.color_win = True
        else:
            for child in self.win.winfo_children():
                child.destroy()
            self.win.get_color()
            self.clipboard_clear()
            self.clipboard_append(self.win.hex)
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App(width=scaled(575), height=scaled(500), bg='white').mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you add the code that loads the image?

Comment: @Mntfr Added it!